# My dialog box is opening for first time but not second time?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've made my own dialog box using jQuery, it's working fine, everything fine, when first time it opens and close successfully, when i  again try to open, but appears nothing? can you tell me what's wrong here?

Here is my source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('a.dialog-window').click(function(){

                    var signUpBox=$(this).attr('href');

                    $(signUpBox).fadeIn(500);

                     $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
                     $('#mask').fadeIn(500);    
                        return false;
                    });

                    $('a.close_dialog_box').click(function(){
                        $('.dialog_box').fadeOut(400, function(){
                            remove();
                        });
                        return false;
                    });
                });
        </script>
        <style>
            .dialog_box{
                width: 70%;
                height: 70%;
                background-color: #520832;
                position: fixed;
                left: 15%;
                top: 15%;            
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 15px 4px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
                -moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 15px 4px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
                box-shadow:         0px 1px 15px 4px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
                -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
                -moz-border-radius: 3px;
                border-radius: 3px;
                display: none;
            }

            .close_dialog_box{
                position: fixed;
                right: 14%;
                top: 10%;
            }            
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#dialog" class="dialog-window">Signup!!</a>

        <div id="dialog" class="dialog_box">
            <a href="#" class="close_dialog_box"><img src="close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>

            <h2 style="color: #E2E2E2; font-family: Aileron, sans-serif; text-align: center;">Signup Now!</h2>

            <form method="post" class="signUp" action="#">

            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: remove  remove(); from $('a.close_dialog_box').click(function(){
                        $('.dialog_box').fadeOut(400, function(){
                            remove();
                        });

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle pls

Comment: To expand on @AnoopJoshi so you understand *why*:  you're removing (`remove()`) the item so it is no longer in the DOM - not just dismissing it (which is what their code does).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the line `remove();` from,

```
$('a.close_dialog_box').click(function(){
    $('.dialog_box').fadeOut(400, function(){
        remove(); <------ Remove this
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the function remove();

so the onclick code will be

```
$('a.close_dialog_box').click(function(){
                        $('.dialog_box').fadeOut(400, function(){
                            //no need of remove
                        });
                        return false;
                    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change

```
$('.dialog_box').fadeOut(400, function(){
    remove();
});
```

to

```
$('.dialog_box').fadeOut(400);
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgjpG/) as well

Answer (score 0):

The line `remove();` is completely removing the dialog box from the html and thus cannot be opened again as it no longer exists. Try removing the `remove();` line from your code and it should work fine.

Answer (score -2):

use dialog box in try block. then use catch block to handle the execption.
                                        }